# php check if row in database exists returns always true

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if an entry in a db-table exists based on two columns 'id' and 'devicetoken'.

I always get true as result from this function, but in the database, there is no such entry. How is that possible?

```
$selectSQL = "SELECT id from devices where devicetoken = ? and id = ?";
echo "token:".$utoken."\n";
echo "id:".$uid."\n";
$resultId = -33;
if ($stmt->prepare($selectSQL)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $utoken, $uid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($resultId);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $resultId;
    if ($resultId == $uid) {
        echo "AA";
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "BB";
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I run the page with this params:

> token:asdf
>
> id:2

I get the output `2AA` which is printed, because `$resultId == $uid`. But how can this even be possible? The select-statement clearly filters on two where-conditions and there is no such entries as token = asdf and id = 2.
the real entry with id = 2 has token value = 'b'.

here is a screenshot of my table:

[image: mysql table]

If I run the code on Mysql Workbench

```
SELECT id from devices where devicetoken = 'b2' and id = 2
```

I get no error and 0 results, which is correct. But from PHP-page it gets a wrong result. How is that possible?

Comment: token is a string and you're using `i`, use `s`. This is a typo question.

Comment: I smell someone formulating an answer; IMHO there shouldn't be.

Comment: aaargh. thank you so much. that was the problem!

Comment: You're welcome Jack, *cheers* you should delete it though, IMHO.

Comment: well typo questions are off-topic as Stack tells us.

Comment: yeah, but what if someone has the same problem and gets a good hint on where the problem could be with your advice?

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer seeing you feel strongly about it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the OP wanted an answer posted:

As I stated in comments, the token is a string and you are passing `i` for "integer" in the bind.

It should be "`s`" for a string.

```
bind_param('si'
```